# Access does not MoveLast Record in Table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using a table in Access.  When I add columns and rows to this table, either manually or programmatically and examine the table the new records are there. The number of rows and columns are correct, both visually and by the program counting them. However, when I use the MoveLast command it moves to the original last record. I can close everything, turn off the computer and rerun, but still can only move to the original Last record.  This happens if I add a single record or multiple records.  Can anyone help ?

Comment: So Many answers completely wrong !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to sort the table, otherwise there is no "first" or "last" record.

Create a simple select query with the table as source and apply the sorting:

```
Select * From YourTable Order By [SomeField]
```

Now use this query as source for your form.

Comment: TestColumn A A A A A A A
AnotherColumn B B B B B B B
CostType SoftwareCosts HardwareCosts Expenses Travel Building TestColumn 
SoftwareCosts Licensing Environment & Infrastructure Training Air Fare Seating  
HardwareCosts Support Laptops Accomodation Taxi Concrete  
Expenses  Servers Telephony Mileage Bricks  
Travel  Physical Memory Meals RailFare Flooring  
Building   Per Diems

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.